# Cannot download Node packages using npm and shell

Tags: node.js

I installed Node 0.10.12 on Windows 7 using msi installer

Before this, I installed python 2.7 and gmake - all of which installed succesfully.

Now, I'm typing

```
"$ sudo npm install -g sax" to download the sax package and nothing is happening. All I get is "...". Just 3 dots.
```

Does this means that downloading is in progress or is something wrong? I guess something is wrong, since I see those dots for 30 minutes and still nothing. I just dont get it.

Also, in the book I read about node, says "/usr/local/lib/node_modules" for the modules folders, but I found the default modules here "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules". Is that wrong? Does it mean something went wrong on the installation?

Comment: You are mixing up instructions for Windows and Linux platforms. Also which Windows are you using ?

Comment: @user568109 I thought this was the syntax for any platform. I use Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: Help keep SO tidy by using the commenting tools and keep your English clear. And, if an answer is correct and has helped you, please mark it so.

Comment: @simonmorley Sorry about that. You are right. I posted this question around 4 in the morning, so I forgot to edit properly. Also, my native language is Greek , not English, but I am trying to keep it clear. I dont have enough reputation to vote up, but at least I clicked the accepted anser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Three dots mean you are running the command inside the node interpreter (Node.js command prompt).

Run `npm install -g sax` from the Windows command line terminal not node.js terminal. Type `cmd` after opening Windows menu and open the program, then enter this command.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. On Windows command line I ran "npm install -g sax". But now says "sax@50.5.4 C:\Users\nerd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sax". Out of curiosity, is that the correct path it should be installed? Or it should be installed on "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules"? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it is the correct path. The global modules are always installed inside your user directory.

Answer (score -1):

"/usr/local/lib/node_modules" would be a UNIX (linux) path. I haven't tried running nodejs on windows but that path should be fine.

sudo will make your command run as admin in linux, in windows you might want to try just "npm install -g sax".

Comment: I've tried everything. Using the "sudo" or not, using the "$" or not, and still nothing. By typing the "npm install -g sax" you suggested, I get "npm should be run outside of the node repl , in your normal shell (Press Control-D to exit)". And I get the same message even if I run it on the node command prompt or the windows command line

Comment: Also, do you think this has to do with the libexecinfo? It is a prerequisite for node. libexecinfo gets installed with msi installer, or I should installed by hand? I can't find any giudelines on how to install it on windows.

Comment: I haven't tried to use nodejs in windows; it looks like user568109 answered your question though. 

If your interested in trying nodejs in linux but don't want to install linux; you might want to check out cloud9 for developing a nodejs app. It's like google docs for code but you also get access to terminal and stuff.