# node.js not recognizing express

Tags: windows, node.js, express

I am just starting development in node and wanted to install node and express. Now i downloaded node from the official website and installed it. Now i also referred some tutorials and [This Link from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386156/cannot-download-node-packages-using-npm-and-shell)
Now the problem i face is that my CMD show something like this [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ECae.jpg) and my node window like this [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnYga.jpg)
i am using windows 7 64 bit OS.
if express --help is not working it means node doesn't recognize express what should i do ? Kindly Help

Comment: Please paste text instead of links to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the wrong package globally. You need to do `npm install express-generator -g`. Then from your command prompt (e.g. `C:\>`) you can use the `express` command.

Comment: it worked... :) I cant upvote sorry but i am truly grateful :)

Comment: but i have a doubt i will be very grateful if you can answer that too. If we have to work in command prompt version of node.js why do they give Node.exe file ("Sorry for my n00bness")

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The `node` program is like `python` in that you can pass it a script and other arguments from the command prompt or shell, but just executing it by itself (either from a prompt or by double-clicking the executable) will start a REPL. I'm not sure what else you're expecting.

Comment: @mcdex i was asking just that thanx so much  :)